# browserify + tsify + babelify; babel gets ignored

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, babeljs, browserify

I want to browserify, tsify and babelify my code. Browserify and one of the other transpilers work, but together they dont. Babel just seems to get ignored (does not even read .babelrc).

I have the following gulp code:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const browserify = require("browserify");
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const tsify = require("tsify");
const babelify = require("babelify");

function build() {

  var b = browserify({
    basedir: '.',
    debug: true,
    cache: {},
    entries: ['src/index.ts'],
    packageCache: {}
  });

  return b
    .plugin(tsify)
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .on("error", function (err) { console.log("Error: " + err.message); })
    .pipe(source('build.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"));
 }

 gulp.task("build", build);
```

With this babelrc

```
{
   "presets": ["minify"]
}
```

And those dependencies

```
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.0",
"babelify": "^10.0.0",
"browserify": "^16.2.3",
"gulp": "^4.0.0",
"tsify": "^4.0.1",
"typescript": "^3.2.2",
"vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0"
```

As said even if I change the babelrc to something like the following I get no errors, it just doesnt minify the code.

Comment: Have you looked at the example? https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/tree/master/examples/babelify

Comment: @cartant Havent had but just did. Seems to work great with the preset es2015 but as I change the preset to minify it throws <code>ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'</code>.

Comment: I don't know what that preset does - or, rather, what module system is used in the code that's emitted when that preset is used. IIRC, it's important to understand that Browserify does not understand ES modules.

Comment: @cartant It minifies the code. I always thought tsify translates ES6 modules to node modules (which browserify understands) as it did when using the es2015 preset

Comment: Whatever it's doing, it sounds very much like Browserify is receiving source that uses ES modules.

Comment: @cartant it does indeed, but why would it work with the es2015 preset then

Comment: Presumably because that preset sees it emit CommonJS modules. I dunno why. I no longer use Browserify, so I've not messed with any of this stuff for a long, long time.

Comment: @cartant Just out of curiosity, what are you using?

Comment: @cartant Just found out that by changing the module value in the tsconfig to <code>"module": "es5"</code> it works (using this example  github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/tree/master/examples/babelify). You may post the answere to get the bounty, thanks alot.

Comment: Just answer it yourself; you figured it out. You won't get your bounty back, but folks might find and upvote your answer in the future. Also, I use Rollup or webpack, these days - depending upon the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I dont exactly know why the above code doesnt work, I found an alternative.

Use the setup provided [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/tsify/tree/master/examples/babelify). Note that in order for it to work you will have to change the value of the `module` key in the tsconfig to be `es5` (instead of `es6`). So that it looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "module": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6"
    }
}
```